# Paying to one address using inputs from multiple addresses under same seed

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli

I am using bitcoin core and I was wondering. If I make a bitcoin payment using bitcoin-cli which has about 50 addresses registered to it. If the payment is for 1 BTC and I pay from the address A1 (let's use A1 instead of an actual address) but A1 doesn't have enough balance will it take money from other wallets automatically to help pay the set amount? If not then how can I make it so?

Edit: I am using 'getnewaddress' when generating these other addresses.

Comment: AFAIK bitcoin-cli doesn't have a way to send a payment "from" a particular address, other than manually using raw transactions. There is a `sendfrom` command that will send from a particular *account*, which may encompass many addresses, but the whole feature of accounts is deprecated and shouldn't be used at all.